# How to Print All Elements with .text?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I get the following error when I try to print matchup:

AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

There are several indexes on the page that will print with .text, but when I go to print all of them, it returns the above error. How do I search and only print the elements that containt ".text"?

'''

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml



vegas_insider = requests.get('https://www.vegasinsider.com/nfl/matchups/', 'r').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(vegas_insider, 'lxml')

# returns 3rd index of class ID
#spread = soup.find_all('td', class_ = 'viSubHeader2 cellBorderL2 headerTextNorm padCenter')[2].text
#closing_line = soup.find_all('td', class_ = 'viCellBg2 cellBorderL1 cellTextNorm padCenter')[2].text
#home_team = soup.find_all('a', class_ = 'tableText')[1].text

matchup = soup.find_all('td', class_ = 'viHeaderNorm').text
```

'''

Comment: Try a `for` loop based on what you get from `find_all()`

Comment: I did 
for team in matchup:
    print(team.text) 
and it worked. thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could just let pandas parse the tables:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.vegasinsider.com/nfl/matchups/'

dfs = pd.read_html(url)
for df in dfs:
    if len(df.columns) > 4:
        print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                  0              1  ...              7          8
0  8:20 PM Game Time         Record  ...  Betting Trend        NaN
1              Teams       Win-Loss  ...            O/U        ATS
2   109 Tampa Bay Â«  (4-1) (1-1 A)  ...            74%  Under: 50
3   110 Philadelphia  (2-3) (0-2 H)  ...            26%   Cover: 1

[4 rows x 9 columns]
                     0              1  ...              7          8
0    9:30 AM Game Time         Record  ...  Betting Trend        NaN
1                Teams       Win-Loss  ...            O/U        ATS
2            251 Miami  (1-4) (1-2 A)  ...            60%  Under: 43
3  252 Jacksonville Â«  (0-5) (0-3 H)  ...            40%   Cover: 6

[4 rows x 9 columns]
                     0              1  ...              7          8
0    1:00 PM Game Time         Record  ...  Betting Trend        NaN
1                Teams       Win-Loss  ...            O/U        ATS
2          253 Houston  (1-4) (0-2 A)  ...            66%  Under: 34
3  254 Indianapolis Â«  (1-4) (0-2 H)  ...            34%  Cover: 17

[4 rows x 9 columns]
                   0              1  ...              7           8
0  1:00 PM Game Time         Record  ...  Betting Trend         NaN
1              Teams       Win-Loss  ...            O/U         ATS
2   255 Green Bay Â«  (4-1) (2-1 A)  ...            74%  Cover: 4.5
3        256 Chicago  (3-2) (2-0 H)  ...            26%   Under: 38

[4 rows x 9 columns]
                    0              1  ...              7            8
0   1:00 PM Game Time         Record  ...  Betting Trend          NaN
1               Teams       Win-Loss  ...            O/U          ATS
2  257 Kansas City Â«  (2-3) (1-1 A)  ...            90%  Cover: 11.5
3      258 Washington  (2-3) (1-2 H)  ...            10%    Under: 44

[4 rows x 9 columns]
                   0              1  ...              7           8
0  1:00 PM Game Time         Record  ...  Betting Trend         NaN
1              Teams       Win-Loss  ...            O/U         ATS
2   259 Minnesota Â«  (2-3) (0-2 A)  ...            43%  Cover: 3.5
3       260 Carolina  (3-2) (2-1 H)  ...            57%    Over: 62

[4 rows x 9 columns]
                   0              1  ...              7          8
0  1:00 PM Game Time         Record  ...  Betting Trend        NaN
1              Teams       Win-Loss  ...            O/U        ATS
2  261 L.A. Chargers  (4-1) (2-0 A)  ...            69%  Under: 40
3   262 Baltimore Â«  (4-1) (2-0 H)  ...            31%  Cover: 25

[4 rows x 9 columns]
                   0              1  ...              7            8
0  1:00 PM Game Time         Record  ...  Betting Trend          NaN
1              Teams       Win-Loss  ...            O/U          ATS
2  263 Cincinnati Â«  (3-2) (1-1 A)  ...            54%  Cover: 19.5
3        264 Detroit  (0-5) (0-2 H)  ...            46%    Under: 45

[4 rows x 9 columns]
                   0              1  ...              7            8
0  1:00 PM Game Time         Record  ...  Betting Trend          NaN
1              Teams       Win-Loss  ...            O/U          ATS
2   265 L.A. Rams Â«  (4-1) (2-0 A)  ...            42%  Cover: 19.5
3    266 N.Y. Giants  (1-4) (0-2 H)  ...            58%     Push: 49

[4 rows x 9 columns]
                   0              1  ...              7          8
0  4:05 PM Game Time         Record  ...  Betting Trend        NaN
1              Teams       Win-Loss  ...            O/U        ATS
2     267 Arizona Â«  (5-0) (3-0 A)  ...            50%  Cover: 26
3      268 Cleveland  (3-2) (2-0 H)  ...            50%   Over: 51

[4 rows x 9 columns]
                   0              1  ...              7          8
0  4:25 PM Game Time         Record  ...  Betting Trend        NaN
1              Teams       Win-Loss  ...            O/U        ATS
2   269 Las Vegas Â«  (3-2) (1-1 A)  ...            59%  Cover: 15
3         270 Denver  (3-2) (1-1 H)  ...            41%   Over: 58

[4 rows x 9 columns]
                   0              1  ...              7         8
0  4:25 PM Game Time         Record  ...  Betting Trend       NaN
1              Teams       Win-Loss  ...            O/U       ATS
2      271 Dallas Â«  (4-1) (1-1 A)  ...            53%  Cover: 2
3    272 New England  (2-3) (0-3 H)  ...            47%  Over: 64

[4 rows x 9 columns]
                   0              1  ...              7           8
0  8:20 PM Game Time         Record  ...  Betting Trend         NaN
1              Teams       Win-Loss  ...            O/U         ATS
2        273 Seattle  (2-3) (2-1 A)  ...            63%  Cover: 2.5
3  274 Pittsburgh Â«  (2-3) (1-2 H)  ...            37%    Push: 43

[4 rows x 9 columns]
                   0              1  ...              6              7
0  8:15 PM Game Time         Record  ...  Betting Trend  Betting Trend
1              Teams       Win-Loss  ...          Money            O/U
2        275 Buffalo  (4-1) (2-0 A)  ...            87%            73%
3      276 Tennessee  (3-2) (1-1 H)  ...            13%            27%

[4 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: I'm just now learning about pandas. This is amazing and with so little code.

What is the point of the if statement? Because there are other tables with <4 columns?

Comment: Yes. So pandas (uses BeautifulSoup under the hood), returns the dataframes as a list. Basically does a find_all('table'). So just trying to sort out the tables of interest here. Which when I looked at it seemed to be any table with more than 4 columns

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As the error says

> You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element

You want a loop, or a list-comprehension

```
matchup = [el.text for el in soup.find_all('td', class_ = 'viHeaderNorm')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're treating them as the same element, find_all returns a list, you can iterate through it instead though.